# Reset State of children widget

Tags: dart, flutter, state

Here is the summary of the code I'm having a problem with:

**Parent widget**

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
    State<HomePage> createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<AsyncLoaderState> _asyncLoaderState = GlobalKey<AsyncLoaderState>();
  List<DateTime> rounds;
  List<PickupModel> pickups;
  DateTime currentDate;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _asyncLoader = AsyncLoader(
      key: _asyncLoaderState,
      initState: () async => await _getData(),
      renderLoad: () => Scaffold(body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
      renderError: ([error]) => Text('Sorry, there was an error loading'),
      renderSuccess: ({data}) => _buildScreen(context),
    );

    return _asyncLoader;
  }

  Widget _buildScreen(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PickupList(pickups),
    );
  }


  Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
    );

    if (picked != null && picked != currentDate) {
      currentDate = picked;
      pickups = await api.fetchPickupList(currentDate);
      setState(() {
      });
    }
  }

  _getData() async {
    rounds =  await api.fetchRoundsList();
    currentDate = _getNextRound(rounds);
    pickups = await api.fetchPickupList(currentDate);
  }
}
```

**Children Widget**

(Listview builds tiles)

```
class PickupTile extends StatefulWidget{
  final PickupModel pickup;

  PickupTile(this.pickup);

  @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
      return PickupTileState();
    }
}

class PickupTileState extends State<PickupTile> {
  Duration duration;
  Timer timer;
  bool _isUnavailable;
  bool _isRunning = false;
  bool _isDone = false;

  @override
    void initState() {
      duration = widget.pickup.duration;
      _isUnavailable = widget.pickup.customerUnavailable;
      super.initState();
    }

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Row(
      children: [
          // UI widgets
      ]
}
```

So I have a parent widget an initial list of pickups which are displayed in the children PickupTile. One can change the date of the pickups displayed using `_selectDate`. This fetches a new list of Pickups which are stored in the parent State, and the children are rebuilt with their correct attributes. However, the State of the children widget (duration, isRunning, isDone...) is not reset so they stay on screen when changing the date.

If feel like I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure out how to reset the State of the children Widget or create new PickupTiles so that when changing the date I get new separate States.

Comment: To begin with, what's the point of your `initState` if you can already access these values from `widget.pickup` ?

Comment: `duration` is incremented every few hundred ms because the Tile serves as a stopwatch, so I thought it would be better to increment an object from the State. Should I increment directly `widget.pickup.duration` ? The `PickupModel` defines duration as final but I guess I can remove it. Starting out with Flutter and I'm kind of lost to best honest